# MongoDB Aggregate - how to have TWO '$lookup' operations work?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have the following aggregate query:

```
db.getCollection('village').aggregate([
{
    "$match": { _id: "111" }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        from: "character",
        localField: "chieftainId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "chieftain"
    },
     "$lookup": {
        from: "character",
        localField: "villagerIds",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "villager"
    }
},
 { "$project" : { "villagerIds" : 0}}
])
```

And this is its result:

```
{
    "_id" : "111",
    "name" : "MyVillage",
    "chieftainId" : "222",
    "reputation" : 0,
    "villagers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "333",
            "name" : "Bortan",
            "age" : 21,
            "bloodlineId" : "7f02191f-90af-406e-87ff-41d5b4387999",
            "villageId" : "foovillage",
            "professionId" : "02cbb10a-6c0f-4249-a932-3f40e12d32c5"
            
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "444",
            "name" : "Blendi",
            "age" : 21,
            "bloodlineId" : "b3a8ffeb-27aa-4e2e-a8e6-b382554f326a",
            "villageId" : "foovillage",
            "professionId" : "45dc9350-c84a-491d-a49a-524834dd5773"
           
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see `villagerIds` has been resolved to `villagers`. However `chieftainId` has not been resolved to `chieftain`. When I omit the second `$lookup` (with villager) then `chieftain` is being resolved successfully. It seems that only one `$lookup` will be effective and not both. Any idea how I can make both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate pipeline for both $lookup

```
db.getCollection('village').aggregate([
{
    "$match": { _id: "111" }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        from: "character",
        localField: "chieftainId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "chieftain"
    }
},
{
     "$lookup": {
        from: "character",
        localField: "villagerIds",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "villager"
    }
},
 { "$project" : { "villagerIds" : 0}}
])
```